# MapMvcAttributeRoutes start page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have an attribute route for my login page. How can i set that page in the routeconfig to be the start page of my application?

My RouteConfig

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.LowercaseUrls = true;

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

My Controller:

```
[Route("Login")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

If I changed this

```
action = "Login"
```

To

```
action = "Index"
```

it's still doesn't work.

Comment: Is that route to default `Index` page broken? Try adding `[Route("~/", Name = "default")]` to `Index` action above if the start page is not displayed.

Comment: Index page is not broken. I'm having a problem upon running the application on the first time. Basically, it should go to Login route, but it gives me an error 'Server Error in '/' Application.' when adding action = "Login" or action = "Index" in route config.